# JavaScript React async/await returning the wrong body?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I'm new to React, and trying it out for a UI project, with a *Java REST* backend.

I'm seeing really crazy stuff happening in the dev tools window.

Every few refreshes, `loadedFilesList` gets the data from the /splitFiles call.

I've confirmed that the *REST* service works correctly.
If I debug and pause on the highlighted line below, `body2` contains the data that can only be from `response1`.

What asynchronous nonsense is going on?

```
  state = {
    splitFilesList: [],
    loadedFilesList: []
  }


  logFields = () => {
      console.log('Vars', `${this.state.loadedFilesList}`)
  }

  async asyncGetSplitFiles()
  {
    let response1 = await fetch('/splitFiles');

    let body1 = await response1.json();
    this.setState({ splitFilesList: body1.files }, () => {this.logFields()});
  }

  async asyncGetLoadedFiles()
  {
    let response2 = await fetch('/loadedFiles');

    let body2 = await response2.json();    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    this.setState({ loadedFilesList: body2.files }, () => {this.logFields()});
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
      this.asyncGetSplitFiles();
      this.asyncGetLoadedFiles();
  }
```

Comment: is your `this.asyncGetLoadedFiles()` dependent on `this.asyncGetSplitFiles();` function call?

Comment: if you can explain " really crazy stuff happening", someone might be able to help you.

Comment: Hi Hussain, "If I debug and pause on the highlighted line below, body2 contains the data that can only be from response1."

Comment: No dependency.  But I would expect body2 to contain the json from response2.  Instead it randomly gets the json from response1.

Comment: Your code seems fine, there is no dependency between `asyncGetLoadedFiles` and `asyncGetSplitFiles`. btw in `componentDidMount` you might need to add `await` keyword to `this.asyncGetSplitFiles()` to run it synchronously  .

Comment: the await fixed it, but why doesn't javascript respect the scope?  'let' is supposed to be block scope according to docs

Comment: there is something else going on, how did you debug it...using devtool debugger ?

Comment: Chrome devtools, though it did it whether or not I was debugging.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201379/discussion-between-hussain-codes-and-djb).

Answer (score 1):

Ok well I fixed it.  Don't understand why though.

```
  async componentDidMount() {
      await this.asyncGetSplitFiles();
      await this.asyncGetLoadedFiles();
  }
```